# Mocha expect 200 or 201

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am learning mocha and node js.

I am testing a `put` HTTP request that can act as a `post` . So I get either a 200 or 201 response back. Both are ok for me. How do I do this with mocha ?

```
    request(localhost)
        .put(`/stuff`)
        .set('Authorization', authHeader)
        .send(serviceReq)
        .expect(200||201, done);
});
```

The above code does not work, how do I `or` with mocha in status codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`supertest` (which I assume you're using) doesn't have an "or" operation, but you can easily create a custom expectation by passing a function in which you can check the status code:

```
request(localhost)
    .put(`/stuff`)
    .set('Authorization', authHeader)
    .send(serviceReq)
    .expect(function(res) {
      if (res.statusCode !== 200 && res.statusCode !== 201) {
        throw Error('unexpected status code: ' + res.statusCode);
      }
    })
```

Documented here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest#expectfunctionres-

Comment: +1 for the answer, like always very concise and strictly to the point, i have got a question please, whenever i chain expect() with a callback with no parameters and then end() i get this worning :
" Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
superagent: double callback bug"
Does this mean that the end() is called implicitly when i use callback with expect()? and thank you again in advance.

Comment: @Alexander the documentation doesn't suggest that. In fact, [this example code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest#expectfunctionres-) shows how `expect(fn)` and `end(fn)` are both used. _Perhaps_ `expect` does something funky when it gets passed a callback that takes no arguments, but that's easy to test.